# Hazelcast Mancenter - Cluster Health

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

We have a hazelcast setup with two nodes. When the hazelcast instance is up and running , the mancenter shows **backup synchronisation in progress** for both the nodes in cluster health section. When we start to load the datas to the maps , the database connections are taking too long to connect. does these two issues related or different , need a deeper explanation of that message that shows in cluster health section. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain your cluster setup. The nodes hardware, the runtime environment, which Hazelcast and Java versions, what client language, ...

Comment: @noctarius hazelcast version is 3.8.2 , java version is SE8 , runtime environment is Linux

Comment: Is this enough @noctarius

Comment: how are those two nodes located? same machine? same datacenter? wan connection in between?

Comment: @noctarius these two nodes reside in the same Linux server we have different applications which communicate through Hazel client xm file to these two nodes to update data !!!!! We have a seperate loader to load all the existing data’s. This also communicate same as the service . Those application and loader logics also reside in the same server where the hazelcast instance resides .

Comment: Why is everything on the same machine? That's not the recommended setup for hazelcast as it renders the whole failover/backup idea useless. Apart from that I'm not sure I get the general idea behind your setup.